# Strip pformat() newlines (\n) from dict in jsonlogger.JsonFormatter

Tags: python, logging

I am using json `jsonlogger.JsonFormatter` for writing json log files as follows (just extracted the important parts of the code). For console, I use a normal `StreamHandler`.

During program execution I collect some statistics in a dict, that I log when the program finishes. I use `pformat` to get a more human readable output, which works nicely on the console streamHandler.

```
from pprint import pformat
logger.info(pformat(stats_dict, indent=2, sort_dicts=False))
```

Console output of dict with pformat:

```
2022-01-29 13:53:43 [INFO   ] extractor    
{ 'search_count': 240,
  'no_response': 0,
  'no_result': 8}
```

But this also leads to the **json formatter** not recognising the key/value tuples of the dictionary correctly, instead the whole dict will be shown as single string-value in the `message` key including the `\n` from pformat:

```
{"asctime": "2022-01-29 13:17:41,430", "levelname": "INFO", "levelno": 20, "module": "extractor", "message": "{ 'search_count': 240,\n  'no_response': 0,\n  'no_result': 8,\n }", "lineno": 463}
```

If I am **not** using `pformat`, then the json file handler will recognize all key/value tuples correctly and log them as such.

```
{"asctime": "2022-01-29 13:53:43,487", "levelname": "INFO", "levelno": 20, "module": "extractor", "message": null, "lineno": 464, "search_count": 240, "no_response": 0, "no_result": 8}
```

here's the part of setting up my handlers:

```
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

def get_json_handler(file_base, path, level):
    path = os.path.join(path, '')
    logfilename = file_base + "_" + level.lower() + ".json"
    json_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(f"{path}{logfilename}", when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=3)
    format = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(levelno)s %(module)s %(message)s %(lineno)s ")
    json_handler.setLevel(level)
    json_handler.setFormatter(format)
    return json_handler

def get_stream_handler(level):
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-7s] %(module)-12s %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    stream_handler.setLevel(level)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(format)
    return stream_handler
```

Is there a easy way to strip the `\n` newlines that were put by the `pformat` in the **json formatter** itself?

Answer (score 1):

Don't preformat the dictionary. You're now passing a string rather than a dict, and this is apparent in the JSON logging output.

Instead add a custom formatter to your consoler logger that can detect when you're passing dictionaries and apply pformat to them. eg.

```py
import logging
import pprint
from copy import copy

class PFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, pformat_args=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pformat_args = pformat_args or {}

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        if isinstance(record.msg, dict):
            new_record = copy(record)
            new_record.msg = pprint.pformat(record.msg, **self.pformat_args)
            return super().format(new_record)
        else:
            return super().format(record)
```

To selectively control when pformat is applied you can use `extra`. For example:

```py
import logging
import pprint
from copy import copy


class PFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, pformat_args=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pformat_args = pformat_args or {}

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        # NB: extra is passed a dictionary, but its keys become
        # attributes of the log record
        pformat = getattr(record, 'pformat', False)
        if pformat:
            if isinstance(pformat, dict):
                # Allow temporary overriding of default args if 
                # pformat is a dict
                pformat_args = dict(self.pformat_args, **pformat)
            else:
                pformat_args = self.pformat_args
            new_record = copy(record)
            new_record.msg = pprint.pformat(record.msg, **pformat_args)
            return super().format(new_record)
        else:
            return super().format(record)
```

Which you might use like:

```py
# setup logger
formatter = PFormatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(name)s: %(msg)s',
    pformat_args={'indent': 2, 'width': 2},
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel('DEBUG')

# actual logging
some_dict = {
    'search_count': 240,
    'no_response': 0,
    'no_result': 8,
}

PFORMAT = {'pformat': True}
 # just a normal log call, no pformat
log.info(some_dict)
# now pretty print
log.info(some_dict, extra=PFORMAT)
# change indent for one call
log.info(some_dict, extra={'pformat': {'indent': 8}})
# back to default indent
log.info(some_dict, extra=PFORMAT)
# apply pformat to anything, not just dicts!
log.info(list(range(20)), extra=PFORMAT)
```

Comment: Thanks Dunes, that works like a charm! I extended the dict-check like so: `if isinstance(record.msg, dict) and record.msg.get('pformat') == 1:` so that I can control, which dicts I want to print pformatted, because I have shorter dicts that I would still like to have on one line.

Comment: Glad it helped. I had something like that originally, but thought it was overkill for the answer. So I just focused on how to use a formatter to delay applying the formatting. I used extras, so that the meta information need not be part of the output. I'll pop an example in.

Comment: Do you have any idea as well, how to make the Email-Handler use linebreaks? I can see in the emails (containing the Json/Dict) that /n is there if I also use the same method on the JsonFormatter but the email clients don't translate this into line breaks.

Comment: I also have a question about your solution, how can I use `pformat_args` in  `def __init__(self, *args, pformat_args=None, **kwargs):` when creating an instance of this class?
I tried `format = PFormatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-7s | %(module)-12s | %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", indent=2)` but it gives me an error....

Comment: I figured out the latter question: `format = PFormatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-7s | %(module)-12s | %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", pformat_args={'indent':2, 'sort_dicts':False})`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it since I don't have your full program and logger etc. But according to the documentation, you can overwrite the loading function of the JsonFormatter. Therefore, as you know could remove the problematic characters and transform back to a dict (not sure if you need to do that or keep a string).

```py
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        if log_record.get('message'):
            # remove '\n'
            message_str = log_record['message'].replace("\n", '')
            # remove last comma
            message_str = "".join(message_str.rsplit(",", 1))
            # transform to dict (required?)
            log_record['message'] = json.loads(message_str)
```